# Text to ERD tool

Tags: erd

I'm looking for a tool that allows me to create Database ERDs via text in similar way that http://www.websequencediagrams.com/ allows for creating sequence diagrams.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one: http://slopjong.de/2011/02/26/whats-erviz/

Erviz, written by Mitsuru Kono, is a tool that makes it easy to create entity-relation models and the best thing it’s free!

Answer (score 2):

The only one I've found apart from Erwiz is a Haskell package called [erd](https://github.com/BurntSushi/erd), which doesn't look as stale as Erwiz does (most recent commit about a month ago, versus 4 years). It works very similarly to Erwiz, converting files formatted like this:

```
[Person]
*name
height
weight
+birth_location_id

[Location]
*id
city
state
country

Person *--1 Location
```

into diagrams that look like this:

[image: Example ERD]